# AWS Amplify build suddenly failing - Node "N/A" is not yet installed

Tags: npm, aws-amplify, amazon-ami

I'm not sure if Amplify is having an outage or what's going on but I made a simple code change to a button and the build is now failing. Interestingly the same commit hash passed on production but failed on staging. When I went to re-deploy a second time it failed on both production and staging. So it definitely seems transient. Unfortunately my support plan is limited so I'm not sure how to go about debugging a root cause.

Failing build #123 logs under 'Frontend'

```
                                 # Starting phase: preBuild
2023-03-24T15:38:18.528Z [INFO]: # Executing command: nvm use 16.13.2
2023-03-24T15:38:18.566Z [WARNING]: N/A: version "16.13.2 -> N/A" is not yet installed.
2023-03-24T15:38:18.567Z [WARNING]: You need to run "nvm install 16.13.2" to install it before using it.
2023-03-24T15:38:18.568Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
2023-03-24T15:38:18.568Z [ERROR]: !!! Non-Zero Exit Code detected
2023-03-24T15:38:18.568Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...
2023-03-24T15:38:18.568Z [INFO]: # Uploading environment cache artifact...
2023-03-24T15:38:18.626Z [INFO]: # Uploaded environment cache artifact
2023-03-24T15:38:18.626Z [INFO]: # Environment caching completed
Terminating logging...
```

Passing build #121 logs under 'Frontend'

```
2023-03-16T17:08:12.517Z [INFO]: # Starting phase: preBuild
                                 # Executing command: nvm use 16.13.2
2023-03-16T17:08:23.423Z [INFO]: Now using node v16.13.2 (npm v8.1.2)
2023-03-16T17:08:23.425Z [INFO]: # Executing command: npm ci
2023-03-16T17:08:41.387Z [WARNING]: npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
2023-03-16T17:08:41.390Z [WARNING]: npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
2023-03-16T17:08:41.615Z [WARNING]: npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
2023-03-16T17:08:41.839Z [WARNING]: npm WARN deprecated
```

I used https://www.diffchecker.com/text-compare/ to compare the 'Provision' step output from both builds and they are identical. I'm wondering if this is an NPM outage, an AMI bug, an Amplify outage, or something else? I checked out the commit from the passing build and forced pushed to deploy it and that build actually isn't even triggering. I'm not sure if it's because it has already been run as a build in Amplify previously or if the github push is also having an outage?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but all of a sudden I have to explicitly tell Amplify to do `nvm install`...

Here are the build instructions before:

```
version: 1
applications:
  - frontend:
      phases:
        preBuild:
          commands:
            - nvm use 16.13.2
            - npm ci
        build:
          commands:
            - nvm use 16.13.2
            - npm run build
      artifacts:
        baseDirectory: /build
        files:
          - '**/*'
      cache:
        paths:
          - node_modules/**/*
    appRoot: js/project_name
```

Here they are after I explicitly added `nvm install`:

```
version: 1
applications:
  - frontend:
      phases:
        preBuild:
          commands:
            - nvm install 16.13.2  # ADDING THIS FIXED THE ISSUE
            - nvm use 16.13.2
            - npm ci
        build:
          commands:
            - nvm install 16.13.2 # ADDING THIS FIXED THE ISSUE
            - nvm use 16.13.2
            - npm run build
      artifacts:
        baseDirectory: /build
        files:
          - '**/*'
      cache:
        paths:
          - node_modules/**/*
    appRoot: js/project_name
```

What's weird is that these builds have been running for ages. They aren't configured via code unfortunately the setup is manual so a simple commit shouldn't have rendered them broken. Still not sure exactly what changed.